# Required fields inside a panel causing validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel that hides/unhides on certain condition. Inside panel, I have some required fields. When I hide the panel then also, I get the error that field is required. below is my code:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddress" runat="server">

<div class="ui-grid-b" >
<div class="ui-block-a ui-margins"  style="width:100%" ><label for="field_address1" ></span><span style="color:red">*&nbsp;</span><b>Address1</b></label>
    
<input autocomplete="off"  id="txtAddress1" type="text" runat="server" />
</div>
</div>
</asp:Panel>

 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="None"  ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Address1 is required" ControlToValidate="txtAddress1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

when I hide the panel in my code behind then, address1 required validator comes on and I get an error. Address1 is required. How can I avoid showing the required validator for address1 when the panel is hiddden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hiding the panel using Visible (i.e `pnlAddress.Visible = false`). Then you can either move the RequiredFieldValidator inside the panel or in your Page_Load (code behind) you can have:

```
RequiredFieldValidator4.Enabled = pnlAddress.Visible;
```